# How can I best implement async into my WPF application?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, asynchronous

I'm working on a WPF application that runs SQL queries and returns a data grid of the results when pressed.
Currently, the structure of my methods as I try to figure out async is as follows:

```cs
public static async Task GenerateImportDataGrid( TextBox TBImportData )
{
    using( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( sqlConnStr ) )
    {
        SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction( "InsertFromFile" );
        using( var package = new ExcelPackage( new FileInfo( TBImportData.Text ) ) )
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
                int rows = worksheet.Dimension.Rows - 1;
                int columns = worksheet.Dimension.Columns - 1;
                int rowOffset = 4; //offset due to headers

                for( int i = 1; i <= rows - rowOffset; i++ ) //loop through each row
                {
                    SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand(
                        string.Format(
                            "INSERT INTO ##COA ( mailPreparerName, barcodeEdoc, errorType, errorCode, errorDescription, errorData, jobID, mailClassEdoc, processingCategoryEdoc, mailOwnerName, scanTime) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}', '{9}', '{10}')",
                            worksheet.Cells[ i + rowOffset, 2 ].Value, worksheet.Cells[ i + rowOffset, 4 ].Value,
                                worksheet.Cells[ i + rowOffset, 8 ].Value, worksheet.Cells[ i + rowOffset, 9 ].Value,
                                worksheet.Cells[ i + rowOffset, 10 ].Value, worksheet.Cells[ i + rowOffset, 11 ].Value,
                                worksheet.Cells[ i + rowOffset, 13 ].Value, worksheet.Cells[ i + rowOffset, 18 ].Value,
                                worksheet.Cells[ i + rowOffset, 19 ].Value, worksheet.Cells[ i + rowOffset, 34 ].Value,
                                worksheet.Cells[ i + rowOffset, 39 ].Value ),
                            conn, transaction );
                    insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                transaction.Commit();
            }
                    
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "EXEC Export", conn );
            SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    
            DataTable resultSet = new DataTable();
            await Task.Run( () => resultSet.Load( reader ) );
    
            DataDisplay results = new DataDisplay( resultSet ); //DataDisplay is just a window containing a DataGrid
            results.Show();
    }
}
```

```cs
private async void Run()
{
    ...
    PB_ProcessProgress.IsIndeterminate = true;
    await Reporting.GenerateImportDataGrid( TBImportData );
}
```

```cs
private void BtnView_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
      ...
      Run();
}
```

Depending on the query ran, my application can get for anywhere between 30 seconds to 20 minutes. I have a progressbar on my application that I would really like to make use of while the numbers are being crunched, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to best implement `async` and `await`, whether it's in my function or at the point that it is being called.

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Replace `cmd.ExecuteReader()` by `await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsyn()`. Declare your method as `async Task` instead of `void`, and call (and await) it in an `async void` Click handler method.

Comment: Not what you were asking but I recommend taking a look at dapper. It provides extension methods on ado make it easier to move from datatables and datasets to lists of dto.

Comment: @Clemens thank you for your response! I tried to implement your suggestions as well as Johnathan Barclay's suggestion to `await Task.Run(() => resultSet.Load(reader));`, but the app still locks up :( can you check my new edit and help me out again?

Comment: @sirius_pain What are the bunch of inserts? Can you add that code?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I've added the code! I know I've neglected using ADO.NET like you suggested, but I'd really like to see if I can do this without using any additional libraries if possible...

Comment: Your still using some blocking calls `ExecuteNonQuery` and `Commit`. Also, you should be parameterising your SQL statements rather than using `string.Join` which is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay replacing `ExecuteNonQuery` with `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` solved the freeze! thanks! I'll be sure to parameterize my queries before rollout, too - I would have completely missed that if not for your suggestion, I love you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADO.NET has `async` equivalents of `Commit` and `ExecuteReaderAsync`.

If you make your method `async` you can use and await these:

```
public static async Task GenerateImportDataGrid(TextBox TBImportData)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnStr))
    using (SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction("InsertFromFile");
    {
        //bunch of inserts are executed as part of the transaction
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
            
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC Export", conn))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        }

        DataTable resultSet = new DataTable();
        resultSet.Load(reader);

        DataDisplay results = new DataDisplay(resultSet); //DataDisplay is just a window containing a DataGrid
        results.Show();
    }
}
```

Doing so will release your UI thread whilst the asynchronous work happens, keeping your application responsive.

---

If you find that `resultSet.Load(reader)` is also expensive, this may also lock up your application.

As this is CPU-bound work, you will have to mitigate this by running on the thread pool:

```
await Task.Run(() => resultSet.Load(reader));
```

Which will also free-up the UI thread.